# Pulling title from API

Tags: php

Alright so I started with something simple just to get me familiar with what exactly I am getting my self into, how ever when tinkering I became lost.

Okay so I am trying to get contents from the following

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://beam.pro/api/v1/users/63662"));
```

what's the best way I can go about doing this?

Currently I can display the username portion using `print $details->username;` and the `id` portion using `print $details->id;` but after this I become lost how could I go about pulling the title for example.

Here is what the Twitter looks like currently in the API 
`"name":"Thursday -- BR 2's [NA] w/ beam.pro/para",`

[Documentation is here](https://developer.beam.pro/api/v1/user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the following:

```
echo $details->channel->name;
```

However, if you're more comfortable with arrays, you could do this:

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://beam.pro/api/v1/users/63662"), true);
echo $details['channel']['name'];
```

Here is the object structure for future reference:

[image]

Comment: How did you display it like what you're doing above? Sorry I am a bit new.

Comment: `print_r($details);` and view the page source :)